# Is it possible to bundle a wasm binary into a JavaScript bundle to avoid a second request?

Tags: browser, webassembly

I have an extremely start time sensitive application where the html has the JavaScript inlined to ensure only one request is made.

I'm investigating writing parts of the application in Rust/wasm but I can't find any resources describing how to inline the wasm binary.

Is it possible to and how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I can convert the `.wasm` file to base64 and load it as an `ArrayBuffer`. This will result in a file-size penalty of 30%

```js
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
  var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
  var len = binary_string.length;
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}

void async function main() {
  const file = 'AGFzbQEAAAABCAJgAX8AYAAAAg8BB2NvbnNvbGUDbG9nAAADAgEBBxEBDWV4cG9ydGVkX2Z1bmMAAQoIAQYAQSoQAAsAFARuYW1lAQQBAAFpAgcCAAEAAAEA'
  const bytes = _base64ToArrayBuffer(file)
  const obj = await WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, window)
  obj.instance.exports.exported_func()
}()
```